# VSTS Azure continuous deployment issue: 401 error

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I'm following instructions on this link to setup continuous deployment for my web app:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/

I'm using VSTS for my repo.

But I'm getting this error:

> Request failed with status code: 401

This is the full stack trace:

> Failed to set up deployment source for web app mywebapp, using Visual
>   Studio Team Services. {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository
>   'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with
>   Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Vso AddWebHook:
>   Access Denied: MyName needs the following permission(s) on the
>   resource PublisherSecurity/someguid to perform this action: Edit
>   Subscription\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.d__81`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: I'm using continuous deployment with VSTS to Azure, however I read somewhere that if you to make azure to automatically pull your repo everytime there is a change then your VSTS needs to be protected using Azure AD.

To accomplish this I just automatically deploy from VSTS to test slot and then swap through staging and production, I invoke the action not azure in this case